# AnythingSlider - pause when interaction made

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I've finally found a carousel that I'm happy with and I'm using AnythingSlider because it's so configurable. One thing I've found from usability sites is that if there is an interaction with the slider then the slider should fall out of the auto play scrolling automatically and not move again until the user requests it too.

Is this something that is doable in AnythingSlider? I've activated pause on hover but it's not really the same thing. Just wondered if there were any other options that you guysknew about?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an option to stop a slide show when an interaction is made because there are many different types of interaction. You can use the API to stop the slideshow. For example, say you have an input and when that input gets focus, stop the slideshow ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/373/)):

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').startStop();
});
```

Whatever interaction that you want to stop the slide show, just call that `startStop()` function. Use `startStop(true)` to restart it, if desired. Check out the other [API functions here](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Usage).